# C++ and command line options

Tags: c++, getopt

Is it bad form to use the GNU getopt in C++ programs? Is there a C++ specific alternative, or should I still just use getopt?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but see: [getopt implementation suitable for proprietary C++ programs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456797/getopt-implementation-suitable-for-proprietary-c-programs) for ideas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using getopt.  There are a multitude of object oriented alternatives floating around including [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/program_options.html), and classes in [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/docs/), and ACE.

Answer (score 5):

In C++  you can also use [**boost::program_options**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know that there's anything wrong with using getopt.  But you might want to look at [Boost.Program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Answer (score 3):

Not at all, `getopt` is perfectly fine in C++.  The Boost::program_options require that the Boost library be installed, which many may not have.

Comment: Boost can be built as static libraries. Otherwise, you'd practically have to ship the dynamic libs with your project *anyway*.

Comment: I mean that the "devel" packages for many Linux distros may not include Boost by default.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: http://michael.dipperstein.com/optlist/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Try CLPP library. It's simple and flexible library for command line parameters parsing. Header-only and cross-platform. Uses ISO C++ and Boost C++ libraries only. IMHO it is easier than Boost.Program_options.

Library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clp-parser

26 October 2010 - new release 2.0rc. Many bugs fixed, full refactoring of the source code, documentation, examples and comments have been corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I like TCLAP (http://tclap.sourceforge.net/) the Templatized C++ Command Line Parser Library.